# double to hex string & hex string to double

Tags: c++, c, double, hex

What I'm trying to do is to convert a double to hex string and then back to double.

The following code does conversion double-to-hex string.

```
char * double2HexString(double a)
{
   char *buf = new char[17]; // double is 8-byte long, so we have 2*8 + terminating \0
   char *d2c;
   d2c = (char *) &a;
   char *n = buf;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
      sprintf(n, "%02X", *d2c++);
      n += 2;
   } 
   *(n) = '\0';
}
```

This seems work, however, I'm not sure how to convert the resulting string back to double.
Please advise :)

Comment: Are you trying to print the raw bytes, or the hexidecimal representation of the number?  Also, do you care about portability of the string itself (not the code)?

Comment: Do you prefer a solution that is portable, easy to code/read, or fast?

Comment: I prefer solution that is easy to code and read. I need this to pass some arguments between programs. Being more specific - first program spawns another and passes to it 2 doubles encoded into hex string. Strager, what do you mean by "portability of the string itself"?

Comment: Portability can be a problem if using this on two different HW plattforms because you use binary form of the data.
Big Endian/Little Endian machine, Network byte order and such stuff should be taken into account.

Answer (score 10):

I am surprised to see nobody has come up with the standard solution, which is the `%a` format specifier in the ISO C99 Standard.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string double2hexastr(double d) {

  char buffer[25] = { 0 };

  ::snprintf(buffer, 25, "%A", d); // TODO Check for errors

  return buffer;
}

double hexastr2double(const std::string& s) {

  double d = 0.0;

  ::sscanf(s.c_str(), "%lA", &d); // TODO Check for errors

  return d;
}


int main() {

  std::cout << "0.1 in hexadecimal: " << double2hexastr(0.1) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Reading back 0X1.999999999999AP-4, it is ";

  std::cout << hexastr2double("0X1.999999999999AP-4") << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: @Jahid The question asked for `double` and **not** for `long double`. If you wish to do it for `long double`, you need the `"%LA"` conversion specifier. You may want to upvote my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *doubleToRawString(double x) {
    const size_t bytesInDouble = 8;

    union {
        double value;
        unsigned char bytes[bytesInDouble];
    } u;

    u.value = x;

    char *buffer = new char[bytesInDouble * 2 + 1];
    unsigned char *input = u.bytes;
    char *output = buffer;

    for(int i = 0; i < bytesInDouble; ++i) {
        sprintf(output, "%02hhX", *input);

        ++input;
        output += 2;
    }

    return buffer;
}

double rawStringToDouble(const char *input) {
    const size_t bytesInDouble = 8;

    union {
        double value;
        unsigned char bytes[bytesInDouble];
    } u;

    unsigned char *output = u.bytes;

    for(int i = 0; i < bytesInDouble; ++i) {
        sscanf(input, "%02hhX", output);

        input += 2;
        ++output;
    }

    return u.value;
}
```

This uses the non-standard `hh` modifier.  If you don't want to use that, use:

```
unsigned int tmp = *input;
sprintf(output, "%02X", tmp);

unsigned int tmp;
sscanf(input, "%02X", &tmp);
*output = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *doubleToRawString(double x) {
    // Assumes sizeof(long long) == 8.

    char *buffer = new char[32];
    sprintf(buffer, "%llx", *(unsigned long long *)&x);  // Evil!
    return buffer;
}

double rawStringToDouble(const char *s) {
    // Assumes sizeof(long long) == 8.

    double ret;
    sscanf(s, "%llx", (unsigned long long *)&ret);  // Evil!
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For MFC, convert double to CString :)

```
CString MFCClass::DoubleToCString(double d, int beforKomma)
{
    char a[17]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    CString str = _T("");
    double dInt=0,dPunkt=0;
    bool is_otr=0;
    if (d<0) {is_otr=1; d=-d;}
    dPunkt = modf(d, &dInt);
    //целая часть
    long ld = (long)dInt;
    long mask = 0xf;
    int it;
    while(ld>0)
    {
        it = ld&mask;
        ld = ld>>4;
        str.Insert(0,a[it]);
    };
    // дробная часть
    //если целая часть 0:
    if (str.GetLength()==0) str += _T("0");
    str += _T(".");
    for (int i=0; i<beforKomma; i++)
    {
        dPunkt*=16;
        dPunkt = modf(dPunkt, &dInt);
        str += a[(int)dInt];
    }

    if (is_otr) str.Insert(0,_T("-"));
    return (str);
}
```

-345.86783907228863 -> "-159.DE2" (beforKomma=3)

Answer (score 0):

Using sprintf is slow, to be honest, but you can revert it with sscanf, doing almost exactly the same thing.

Well, actually, you'd have to copy each two characters to a buffer string, to decode each individually. My first try, below is incorrect:

```
double hexString2Double(char *buf)
{
  char *buf2 = new char[3];
  double a;
  char* c2d;
  c2d = (char *) &a;
  int i;

  buf2[2] = '\0'

  for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    buf2[0] = *buf++;
    buf2[1] = *buf++;
    sscanf(buf2, "%X", c2d++);
  }

  return a;
}
```

You see, %X is decoded as an int, not as a byte. It might even work, depending on low-ending/high-endian issues, but it's basically broken. So, let's try to get around that:

```
double hexString2Double(char *buf)
{
  char *buf2 = new char[3];
  double a;
  char* c2d;
  c2d = (char *) &a;
  int i;
  int decoder;

  buf2[2] = '\0'

  for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    buf2[0] = *buf++;
    buf2[1] = *buf++;
    sscanf(buf2, "%X", &decoder);
    c2d++ = (char) decoder;
  }

  return a;
}
```

Barring syntax errors and such, I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same procedure should do

```
void hex2double(const char* buf, double& a)
{
   char tmpbuf[3]={0};
   char *d2c;
   unsigned int tmp;
   d2c = (char *) &a;
   char *n = buf;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
      tmpbuf[0]=*buf++;
      tmpbuf[1]=*buf++;
      sscanf(tmpbuf, "%X", &tmp);
      *d2c++=tmp;
   }
}
```

Quick & dirty.

Note, however, that this is playing with fire. First, your hex strings are only usable on machines with the same double format, and the same endianness. Second, the conversion functions are short on strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  union double_ull_t {
    double d;
    unsigned long long u;
  } x;
  scanf("%lf",&x.d);
  printf("%016llX %lf\n",x.u,x.d);
  scanf("%016llX",&x.u);
  printf("%016llX %lf\n",x.u,x.d);
}
```

Maybe not the most efficient solution, but the easiest to code.

Comment: looks like strager beat me to this particular approach, and with more applicable implementation

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a union and avoid this bad habit:

char *d2c;

d2c = (char *) &a;

For just printing its not bad, its when you try to modify d2c and then use a is when you get into trouble.  (same is true for any two variables or pointers (or arrays) sharing the same (theoretical) memory.

```
union
{
    double f;
    unsigned long ul;
} myun;

myun.f = a;
printf("0x%lX",myun.ul);

to go the other way (scanf is also a very dangerous function that should be avoided).

myun.ul=strtoul(string,NULL,16);
a=myun.f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below function, to convert double to hexadecimal.

```
char * double2HexString(double a) 
{ 
   char *buf = new char[17]; // double is 8-byte long, so we have 2*8 + terminating \0 
   char *d2c; 
   d2c = (char *) &a; 
   char *n = buf; 
   int i; 
   for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
   { 
      sprintf(n, "%02X", *d2c++); 
      n += 2; 
   }  
   *(n) = '\0'; 
}
```

passing 1.0 & 16.0 to this function, the return values observed are 000000000000FF37 & 0000000000003040 respectively. I think we should get 1 & 10.