# Full variation of Random numbers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to generate 64 bit random numbers using the following code. I want the numbers in binary,but the problem is I cant get all the bits to vary. I want the numbers to vary as much as possible

```
void PrintDoubleAsCBytes(double d, FILE* f)
{

f = fopen("tb.txt","a");

  unsigned char a[sizeof(d)];
  unsigned i;
  memcpy(a, &d, sizeof(d));
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++){
    fprintf(f, "%0*X", (CHAR_BIT + 3) / 4, a[sizeof(d)-1-i]);

  }
   fprintf(f,"\n");
 fclose(f); /*done!*/
}

int main (int argc, char *argv)
{

int limit = 100 ;
double a, b;                
double result;
int i ;           
printf("limit = %d", limit );

for (i= 0 ; i< limit;i++)
    {
    a= rand();
    b= rand();
    result = a * b;
    printf ("A= %f B = %f\n",a,b);
    printf ("result= %f\n",result);
    PrintDoubleAsCBytes(a, stdout); puts("");
    PrintDoubleAsCBytes(b, stdout); puts("");
    PrintDoubleAsCBytes(result, stdout); puts("");

    }
}
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
41DAE2D159C00000        //Last bits remain zero, I want them to change as well as in case of the result
41C93D91E3000000
43B534EE7FAEB1C3
41D90F261A400000
41D98CD21CC00000
43C4021C95228080
41DD2C3714400000
41B9495CFF000000
43A70D6CAD0EE321
```

How do I do I achieve this?I do not have much experience in software coding

Comment: Generating a random binary floating-point number is nontrivial.  Most of the popular obvious techniques out there (e.g. generating a random integer in the range [0, 2^53) and then dividing by 2^53) are subtly wrong.  The correct algorithm is given here: http://allendowney.com/research/rand/  His algorithm only generates numbers in the half-open interval [0, 1), but you can safely scale the result to whatever interval is required.

Comment: @Zack He wants to generate a random 64 bit integer, not a random floating point number.

Comment: So dou you want a randomized floating point number or just 64 random bits?

Comment: @Patashu I see `double` in the code, not `uint64_t`.  Maybe that's another mistake.

Comment: I want 64bit randomized Floating Point number, not just 64 random bits. I add the first two floating point numbers to get the answer and verify using my hardware

Comment: Basically I use this to verify my hardware design of the same

Comment: @Debian Then generate a random 64 bit integer and cast it to double. Floating point and integer are just different treatments you can apply to the underlying bits.

Comment: @Patashu That won't do what the OP wants, and neither will proper type-punning (e.g. with a union) -- unless the OP really wants to waste a lot of validation time on all 2^53 of the the NaNs, I suppose.

Comment: @Zack Either the OP wants 'all bits to vary' and wants to validate all NaNs or he doesn't. What is the answer, then?

Comment: @Debian I just found a good library for random numbers, but it's for C++ not C: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: @Patashu Fair point, but given that they're trying to verify *arithmetic*, I am assuming that they want to test a wide variety of normal and perhaps also denormal numbers, but probably *not* Inf and NaN handling, which would be better done with special case code.

Comment: @Patashu, I dont care if it is in C / C++/Java but I haven't used these languages extensively. I know only the basics

Comment: @Zack, yes you are right I want to do some extensive testing

Answer (score 3):

In Java it is very easy:

```
Random rng = new Random(); //do this only once

long randLong = rng.NextLong();
double randDoubleFromBits = Double.longBitsToDouble(randLong);
```

In C I only know of a hack way to do it :)

---

Since RAND_MAX can be as low as 2^15-1 but is implementation defined, maybe you can get 64 random bits out of `rand()` by doing masks and bitshifts:

```
//seed program once at the start
srand(time(NULL));

uint64_t a = rand()&0x7FFF;
uint64_t b = rand()&0x7FFF;
uint64_t c = rand()&0x7FFF;
uint64_t d = rand()&0x7FFF;
uint64_t e = rand()&0x7FFF;
uint64_t random = (a<<60)+(b<<45)+(c<<30)+(d<<15)+e;
```

Then stuff it in a union and use the other member of the union to interpret its bits as a `double`. Something like

```
union
{
    double d;
    long l;
} doubleOrLong;

doubleOrLong.l = random;
double randomDouble = doubleOrLong.d;
```

(I haven't tested this code)

---

EDIT: Explanation of how it should work

First, `srand(time(NULL));` seeds rand with the current timestamp. So you only need to do this once at the start, and if you want to reproduce an earlier RNG series you can reuse that seed if you like.

`rand()` returns a random, unbiased integer between 0 and RAND_MAX inclusive. RAND_MAX is guaranteed to be at least 2^15-1, which is 0x7FFF. To write the program such that it doesn't matter what RAND_MAX is (for example, it could be 2^16-1, 2^31-1, 2^32-1...), we mask out all but the bottom 15 bits - 0x7FFF is 0111 1111 1111 1111 in binary, or the bottom 15 bits.

Now we have to pack all of our 15 random bits into 64 bits. The bitshift operator, `<<`, shifts the left operand (right operand) bits to the left. So the final uint64_t we call random has random bits derived from the other variables like so:

`aaaa bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbc cccc cccc cccc ccdd dddd dddd dddd deee eeee eeee eeee`

But this is still being treated as a uint64_t, not as a double. It's undefined behaviour to do so, so you should make sure it works the way you expect on your compiler of choice, but if you put this uint64_t in a union and then read the union's other double member, then you'll (hopefully!) interpret those same bits as a double made up of random bits.

Comment: You need `(((uint64_t)rand()) << 32) + rand()` or the left shift will not do what you intended here.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 2^15-1 and it is exactly that in my compiler.

Comment: @undefined behaviour Is there a better way?

Comment: @Patashu better. adj. *Of a more excellent or effective type or quality*. You'll have to elaborate.

Comment: @undefined behaviour Interpreting the bits of an uint64_t as though it were the bits of a double without invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Patashu "Interpreting the bits of an uint64_t as though it were the bits of a double" would also be invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: @undefined behaviour So how do I create doubles that have completely randomized bits without invoking undefined behaviour? Lol

Comment: I have no idea , what's going on . COuld you please elobrate

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Presumably because he doesn't know any other way to eliminate bias.

Comment: @Patashu Consider reading a book about floating points and a book about secure random generation, which are the two areas that the OP needs an answer covering.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze Because 0x8F is the bottom 15 bits - 0111 1111 1111 1111

Comment: @Debian I have elaborated as requested

Comment: @Patashu How so? Pull out your calculator.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour “Using a different member of a union is undefined behaviour.” No, Using unions for type-punning is explicitly allowed by C99 TC3 footnote 82.

Comment: 0111 1111 1111 1111 is 0X7FFF; But i cant figure out how to vary all the bits

Comment: @PascalCuoq TC3 is not the official C99, it's a version intermediate to C99 and C2011.

Comment: I did try with union, but the thing is `random` has a range and what I am looking for exceeds the range,. I will try the other one.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze TC3 is every bit a Technical Corrigendum. It updates C99 just like C11TC1 updates C11. “Technical Corrigendum 3 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 Cor. 3:2007(E)) was published in 2007. It can be obtained free of charge from ISO” http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards

Comment: If your `RAND_MAX` is 32767, that is an indication that the C library's RNG is no good and you should switch to a more sophisticated third-party RNG, e.g. [ISAAC](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html).  (Yes, I consider LCRNGs to be "no good" by modern standards.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your platform, but assuming IEEE 754, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), why not explicitly handle the internal double format?

(Barring mistakes), this generates random but *valid* doubles. 
[  Haven't quite covered all bases here, e.g. case where `exp = 0` or `0x7ff` ]

```
double randomDouble()
{
    uint64_t buf = 0ull;

    // sign bit
    bool odd = rand()%2 > 0;
    if (odd)
        buf  = 1ull<<63;

    // exponent

    int exponentLength = 11;

    int exponentMask = (1 << exponentLength) - 1;

    int exponentLocation = 63 - exponentLength;

    uint64_t exponent = rand()&exponentMask;

    buf += exponent << exponentLocation;

    // fraction

    int fractionLength = exponentLocation;
    int fractionMask  = (1 << exponentLocation) - 1;

    // Courtesy of Patashu

    uint64_t a = rand()&0x7FFF;
    uint64_t b = rand()&0x7FFF;
    uint64_t c = rand()&0x7FFF;
    uint64_t d = rand()&0x7FFF;

    uint64_t fraction = (a<<45)+(b<<30)+(c<<15)+d;
    fraction = fraction& fractionMask;
    buf += fraction;

    double* res = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&buf);
    return *res;
}
```

Comment: The question was tagged as C, not C++.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze It was, but confusingly in the comments in the question the OP says that he is fine if it's in C++ or Java. (Not sure if that means it can be implemented in C++ or Java, or that if he reads it in C++ or Java he'll understand what you're doing...)

Comment: I just need to generate a few million test cases on to a file to run my hardware simulation.

Comment: How did you arrive at a few million?

Answer (score 0):

Use could use this:

```
void GenerateRandomDouble(double* d)
{
  unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)d;
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(d); i++)
    p[i] = rand();
}
```

The problem with this method is that your C program may be unable to use some of the values returned by this function, because they're invalid or special floating point values.

But if you're testing your hardware, you could generate random bytes and feed them directly into said hardware without first converting them into a `double`.

The only place where you need to treat these random bytes as a `double` is the point of validation of the results returned by the hardware.

At that point you need to look at the bytes and see if they represent a valid value. If they do, you can `memcpy()` the bytes into a `double` and use it.

The next problem to deal with is overflows/underflows and exceptions resulting from whatever you need to do with these random `doubles` (addition, multiplication, etc). You need to figure out how to deal with them on your platform (compiler+CPU+OS), whether or not you can safely and reliably detect them.

But that looks like a separate question and it has probably already been asked and answered.

Comment: Is there anyway I can concatenate the two numbers make a larger sum ? and reuse the code I got it from you ?

Comment: What two numbers? Of what type? What do you mean exactly by "concatenate"? Larger than what?